# Facing an error when using TotalOrderPartitioner MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I have written the below program. 
I have run it without using TotalOrderPartitioner and it has run well. So I don't think there are any issues with Mapper or Reducer class as such.

But when I include the code for TotalOrderPartitioner i.e. write the partition file and then to put it in DistributedCache, I am getting following error: Really clueless how to go about it.

[train@sandbox TOTALORDERPARTITIONER]$ hadoop jar totalorderpart.jar average.AverageJob counties totpart

//counties is input directory and totpart is output directory

> 16/01/18 04:14:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to
>   process : 4 16/01/18 04:14:00 INFO partition.InputSampler: Using 6
>   samples 16/01/18 04:14:00 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded &
>   initialized native-zlib library 16/01/18 04:14:00 INFO
>   compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
>   java.io.IOException: wrong key class:
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable is not class
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$RecordCompressWriter.append(SequenceFile.java:1380)
>         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.InputSampler.writePartitionFile(InputSampler.java:340)
>         at average.AverageJob.run(AverageJob.java:132)      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)         at
>   average.AverageJob.main(AverageJob.java:146)      at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)       at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)         at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

**My code**

```
package average;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.InputSampler;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class AverageJob extends Configured implements Tool {

public enum Counters {MAP, COMINE, REDUCE};

public static class AverageMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text mapOutputKey = new Text();
    private Text mapOutputValue = new Text();
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] words = StringUtils.split(value.toString(), '\\', ',');
        mapOutputKey.set(words[1].trim());

        StringBuilder moValue = new StringBuilder();
        moValue.append(words[9].trim()).append(",1");
        mapOutputValue.set(moValue.toString());
        context.write(mapOutputKey, mapOutputValue);

        context.getCounter(Counters.MAP).increment(1);
    }
}

public static class AverageCombiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text combinerOutputValue = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int count=0;
        long sum=0;
        for(Text value: values)
        {
            String[] strValues = StringUtils.split(value.toString(), ','); 
            sum+= Long.parseLong(strValues[0]);
            count+= Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]);
        }
        combinerOutputValue.set(sum + "," + count);
        context.write(key, combinerOutputValue);

        context.getCounter(Counters.COMINE).increment(1);
    }
}


public static class AverageReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {


    private DoubleWritable reduceOutputKey = new DoubleWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int count=0;
        double sum=0;
        for(Text value: values)
        {
            String[] strValues = StringUtils.split(value.toString(), ',');
            sum+= Double.parseDouble(strValues[0]);
            count+= Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]);
        }

        reduceOutputKey.set(sum/count);
        context.write(key, reduceOutputKey);

        context.getCounter(Counters.REDUCE).increment(1);
    }

}


@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());

    Path in = new Path(args[0]);
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(AverageMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(AverageCombiner.class);

    job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);

    job.setReducerClass(AverageReducer.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(6);

    InputSampler.Sampler<Text, Text> sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler<Text, Text>(0.2, 6, 5);
    InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);

    String partitionFile = TotalOrderPartitioner.getPartitionFile(conf);
    URI partitionUri = new URI(partitionFile + "#" + TotalOrderPartitioner.DEFAULT_PATH);
    job.addCacheFile(partitionUri);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result=0;
    try
    {
        result = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new AverageJob(), args);
        System.exit(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TotalOrderPartitioner does not run its sampling on the output of the Mapper, but on the input dataset. Your input format has LongWritable as key and Text as value. Instead, you are trying to call RandomSampler claiming that your format has Text as key and Text as value. This is a mismatch that InputSampler finds when it runs, hence the message

> wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Meaning that it was trying to find Text as key (based on your parametrization) but it found LongWritable instead.